# Django Admin: Getting request in ModelForm's constructor

Tags: django, admin, django-forms, init

The below code removes certain values from a drop down menu. 
It works fine but I want to remove the value if the user lacks certain permissions.
How can I access request.user in the ModelForm's constructor? Or is there a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

```
class AnnouncementModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AnnouncementModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["category"].queryset = AnnouncementCategory.objects.filter(can_post=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here is how I solved it:

```
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == "category" and not request.user.has_perm('can_post_to_all'):
        kwargs["queryset"] = AnnouncementCategory.objects.filter(can_post=True)
        return db_field.formfield(**kwargs)
    return super(AnnouncementAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I access request.user in the ModelForm's constructor?

To use it in the Form constructor, just pass the request to it.

```
class AnnouncementModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AnnouncementModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        qs = request.user.foreignkeytable__set.all()
        self.fields["category"].queryset = qs
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Are you sure about that though? Because I am getting this TypeError:
__init__() takes at least 2 non-keyword arguments (1 given)

Comment: Pass the "request" argument into the Class creation! How else does it get it? AnnouncementModelForm(request)